# Gotchas’: Using jQueryUI to make popups in Visualforce pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, popup

Most of the times we face issues while we integrate jQuery UI popups in Visual Force page. I was also struggling a lot as i was facing the same issues. And I found one article which helped me in fixing some of the common issues while dealing with jQuery popups. So I thought of sharing with you guys. This may be helpful for someone facing same kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of conflict when we use jquery with visual force pages.

Often times the popup seems to annony developers. Whenever we invoke a .dialog() menthod on any div that is inside the `<apex:form>`, it will move the dialog out of the `<apex:form>` which you never wanted.

To fix this, make sure your `<apex:form>` tag has an ID specified. Then use jQuery to find it and put the popup back inside the `<form>` section. So, assuming my `<form>` tag has an id that renders as ‘ThePageID:TheFormID’ the code would look like this:

```
j$("#MyPopup").dialog({modal: true, autoOpen: false }).parent().appendTo(j$("#ThePageID\\:TheFormID"));
```

The datePicker on a popup is most annoying.Either it will be invisible or we wont be able to change the date using the datePicker.

datePicker goes behind the popup: This happens because of the z-index issues. We need to keep the z-index of a datePicker greater the the z-index of the popup dialog.

```
$("#MyPopup").dialog({modal: true, zIndex: 9 });
```

Not able to change date through datePicker on a jQuery Popup: This is the most common problem that i found. I also faced this problem and was not able to understand why this happens. So i found a hack to fix this problem. I added a class "ui-dialog" to datePicker and it worked fine.

```
$('#datePicker').addClass('ui-dialog');
```

Today Link on datePicker doesnot work: To fix this issue add the below code.

```
jQuery('.calToday').click(function () {
                $('#datePicker').css("display", "none");
            });
```

Here is a very nice article that address common issues that we face while using jQuery UI with Visual Force.

http://improveit360.blogspot.in/2010/09/gotchas-using-jqueryui-to-make-popups.html

Comment: Rather than just post a link can you add any more detail to your answer?

Comment: @Girbot This is just a knowledge sharing post. I have added some issues which i myself faced while dealing with jquery popups.